# How can live search / search suggestions be implemented using Dojo?

Tags: javascript, ajax, search, dojo

I want to implement a 'live search' or 'search suggestions' feature in a web application that uses the Dojo Framework. It would be similar to the way Google and Bing searches display matches as you type: when you type in the search box, a list of potential matches appears below. Searches would be performed server side, with the results sent back to the browser using AJAX.

Does anyone know of a good way to implement this using Dojo?

Here are some potential options:

- **The built-in widget dijit.form.ComboBox**
  This has very similar functionality, but I've only seen it used with limited data sets. The examples always use small lists (such as the 50 states in USA) and preload the entire data set for client-side filtering. However I presume I could hook it up to a dojox.data.JsonQueryRestStore for server-side search — can anyone confirm whether that works?
- **QueryBox http://marumushi.com/code/querybox/**
  This implementation mainly does the job, but it has some minor bugs and doesn't look like it's being maintained. I'd have to do some bugfixes on the code before using it.
- **Medryx http://blog.medryx.org/2008/09/10/dijitsearch-part-2/**
  This also looks like it does the job, but it is described as 'alpha-level' code and the link to the code seems to be broken...

I could probably make one of the above work, but I'd like to know if there are any better alternatives out there.

Comment: Hi there. I am trying to do the same and saw this post. Any chance of you posting your code for Dojo 1.5/6?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I implemented it 5 years ago when Dojo was at 0.2:

- http://www.lazutkin.com/blog/2005/12/23/live-filtering/

While the code is ancient, it is trivial, and hopefully it'll give you ideas on how to attack it. The rough sketch:

- Attach an event handler to your input box, which is triggered on changes — use "onkeyup" to detect a change in the input box.
- Wait until user stopped typing by setting a timer in your event handler, if it is not set yet. 200-500ms are good waiting times.

  - The timeout plays a dual role:

    - It throttles our requests to a server to prevent overloading.
    - It plays on our perception of time and our typing habits.
- If our timeout is up, and we don't wait for a server ⇒ send server a string we have so far.
- If we are still waiting for a server, cancel the request and ask again.

  - This part is app-specific: we don't want to overload a server, and sometimes a server cannot handle broken connections well.
  - In the example I don't cancel the XHR call, but wait it to finish first before submitting new request.
- Server responds with relevant results, which are promptly shown.

In the blog post I implemented it as a widget. Obviously the exact packaging is up to you.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is remarkably close to what I was looking for. I am currently writing an updated script for Dojo 1.5 and will probably post it here once I'm done.

Comment: Please do. This is a useful piece of code, which I can use myself. ;-)

Comment: i knew this is an old post. can you please share the latest code? I am currently working on a same feature using dojo. Appreciate it.

Comment: @AlexW. I refreshed the URL.